# Exception in Dynamic Report

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7, dynamic-reports

Hi I am trying to generate dynamic report in **NetBeans7 IDE, java6, glassfish3.2 environment.**
I am creating project using **java> web application.**   **I used below jars**

commons-collections-3.2.1
commons-digester-2.0
dynamicreports-1.3.0
dynamicreports-adhoc-4.0.1
dynamicreports-core-4.0.1
itext-2.1.7
jasperreports-6.1.0
commons-logging-1.2
commons-logging-1.2-javadoc
common-lang3.jar

but I am getting 
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate**

I investigate the issue and find that 
I have to add 

**1)common-lang3.jar 

2)and common-lang3.jar is missing inside WEB-INF>lib ,**


I added mentioned jar and
it is also available in WEB-INF>lib.
but still I am facing same issue.

find the below exception while running java file

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/Validate
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.component.DRList.setType(DRList.java:78)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.component.DRList.<init>(DRList.java:50)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRBand.<init>(DRBand.java:41)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRReport.init(DRReport.java:113)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.base.DRReport.<init>(DRReport.java:97)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.ReportBuilder.<init>(ReportBuilder.java:60)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.<init>(JasperReportBuilder.java:95)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.DynamicReports.report(DynamicReports.java:65)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.examples.adhoc.DynamicReporting.main(DynamicReporting.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.Validate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 9 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

**my code:**

```
public class DynamicReporting{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws DRException, FileNotFoundException{
        JasperReportBuilder report= DynamicReports.report();
        report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/report.pdf")));
        System.out.print("Report generated");
    }
}
```

can any one suggest what I am missing.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

From this `dynamicreports-core-4.0.1` in your jar list, I can say that you are using 4.0.1 version, So you do not need `dynamicreports-1.3.0` this.

I just downloaded dependencies from below link,

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicreports/files/dynamicreports/4.0.1/

And all you need to run snippet of yours is this list of jars in your project class path,

[image]

You can see that this does not match with yours so you are mixing lots diff versions of jar.

**Note:**  All this jars can be found under that links.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dynamic Reports 4.1.1 released, you should opt for JasperReports 6.2.2

DynamicReports 4.1.0 released JasperReports 6.2.0, 
DynamicReports 4.0.2 released JasperReports 6.1.1
etc.

http://www.dynamicreports.org/news

And the libraries to be added should be as follows. I took the same mistake and solved it by loading these libraries,I hope it helps.

[image]

result:
[image]